# Can VAST tag be JSON but not XML?

Tags: video, ads, vast, vpaid

The advertising network i'm trying to get video ads from gives VAST tag code in JSON format. All the video players i try are giving me invalid XML error, and it is pretty much right as the file is json-formatted object. Can someone give me an advice what is a possible solution in this situation?

Comment: does the network not offer XML as an option? seems like a problem they need to solve

Comment: No actually they host only json-formatted way. I opened a couple of tickets to them, but seems all of their users are satisfied with only that format. I really don't know what to do.

Comment: worst case get the JSON object and reformat it to XML before passing to the video player...